# Calendar returning wrong value for Calendar.MONTH

Tags: java, calendar

I have a problem with my month

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    GregorianCalendar tgl;
    tgl = new GregorianCalendar ();

    System.out.println("Tanggal Sekarang : " +
            tgl.get (Calendar.DATE) + "/" +
            tgl.get (Calendar.MONTH) + "/" +
            tgl.get (Calendar.YEAR));
}
```

The result is :

```
Date now : 27/3/2013
```

Comment: now the date is 27/4/2013
but, the result is 27/03/2013

Answer (score 6):

`Calendar.MONTH` is zero-based. So April will appear as `3`.

Instead, if you want to format a date use [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) and call `getTime()` on your calendar instance to get a `Date`:

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
System.out.println(dateFormat.format(tgl.getTime()));
```

Comment: so, what i have to do?

Comment: @Firman Alamsyah : Nothing more than `tgl.get (Calendar.MONTH) + 1`. I would use a different approach though.

Comment: if i do that the result is 27/17/2013

Comment: @FirmanAlamsyah Did you accidentally do `mm` rather than `MM`?